# Sql Server: Select..Into #TempTable with variable assignment on Temp Table name

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, variables, temp-tables

I have a question here.I better paste my code first

```
SET @Sql = 'DECLARE @Date_From VARCHAR(10);
            DECLARE @Date_To VARCHAR(10);
            DECLARE @TempTable VARCHAR(500);
            SET @TempTable = #'+@TblName+'; 
            SET @Date_From = '''+CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),DATEADD(d,DATEDIFF(d,0,GETDATE()),0)-@DayPrior,120)+''';
            SET @Date_To = '''+CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),DATEADD(d,DATEDIFF(d,0,GETDATE()),0)-@DayPrior,120)+''';
            '+ @Sql
```

I try to print out @Sql using PRINT
and i get this result

```
DECLARE @Date_From VARCHAR(10);
DECLARE @Date_To VARCHAR(10);
DECLARE @TempTable VARCHAR(500);
SET @TempTable = #RawData_New; 
SET @Date_From = '2011-04-05';
SET @Date_To = '2011-04-05';

Select Distinct Coloum1,Coloum2 into @TempTable 
from RawData_New with(nolock)  
here Convert(varchar(10), Date_Tm, 120) Between @Date_From And @Date_To
```

I get an error after executing this sql,i get an error:

```
Incorrect syntax near '@TempTable'.
```

Is there any Constraint to this **#** symbol or inside the select Statement around **INTO**?

I tried that not variable assigment on @TempTable that i directly put the @TempTable Value inside the sql like

```
Select Coloum1,Coloum2 into #RawData_New
from RawData_New with(nolock)  
here Convert(varchar(10), Date_Tm, 120) Between @Date_From And @Date_To
```

Its works fine and i get my expected result? is there any solution to solve this?

Thanks you.

PS: I am quite new to T-Sql, Please dont hesitated to point out my mistake.We all Learn from Mistake.Any Sorry for my poor English Level.

Regards:

LiangCK

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a couple of issues:

- You can't assign a table name like that.  You need to assign the variable to the string representing the table name: `SET @TempTable = ''#'+@TblName+''';`  The extra quotes will make the table a string
- You need to make the second query Dynamic SQL as well.  Basically parse it with the table name at runtime:

..

```
'Select Coloum1,Coloum2 into' + @TableName +'
from SPC.dbo.Lube_RawData_New with(nolock)  
where Convert(varchar(10), Date_Tm, 120) Between @Date_From And @Date_To'
```

Comment: Hi @JNK. ya, i tried your example before. its work. But problem is this sql is actually get from a table that preset by users that mean they type in from start to end.Thats from select....where.I trying to achieve more user friendly in term of that.Do you get what i meant? and is there another way to resolve it?

Comment: @LiangCk - I don't get why that is an issue.  Can you elaborate in your question?

Comment: @LiangCk Then you have an application design issue.  I can't think of anyone who would **EVER** recommend letting end users input sql queries for any reason.  **EVER**

Comment: @JNK...I agree what you said about this...haha
But unfortuanly this is required by user ==", and we are developing according to their requirement..but on the first round(mean when deploy) we made all the sql setting for them.
Ps: the most of user is IT person/Power User.

Comment: Then you need to make a decision.  Do you want to use dynamic table names, or do you want it to be easy for the end user?  Those are the options and they are mutually exclusive.  Also, if they are "power users" they should be able to understand dynamic SQL.  If they don't then they probably have no business writing queries.

Comment: @JNK...
Just One Question: for Scenario if i using a static #TableName rather than dyanmic, Mean each sql i bount with Fixed select...into #Table. Is there an issues? Because basically this #table is used for Temp insert into a table and continues then its flush all data into a permernet table? if i do so? is that an issues?

Comment: @LiangCk - That should work fine.  The other variables you are using should work OK, but you can't use variables for object names (fields, tables, databases, etc) without using dynamic SQL.

Comment: I Get what you mean,then i shall play around with that.
By the way, Thanks for time and Advice @JNK. Appreciate its a lot.